Which type of GAN will be appropriate for regression?
I designed a cGAN for a regression problem and prediction of some values like the mass.
I've tried different activation functions and optimizers as well as loss functions. but my model is not stable and I can not get meaningful prediction results.
The number of neurons in the layers of the generator and discriminator should be either increasing or decreasing?
I wonder if you have any idea for help?
